# RegEx pattern to handle URL with dates

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I moved to a new website and it mangled up my URL's. Now blog posts are accessible from multiple URL's and would like to redirect one pattern to the other.

I am trying to redirect the first case to the second case:

```
~/blogs/johndoe/john-doe/2014/03/14/test-article1 =>
~/blogs/john-doe/2014/03/14/test-article1

~/blogs/jimjones/jim-jones/2014/03/14/test-articleb =>
~/blogs/jim-jones/2014/03/14/test-articleb
```

How do I create a pattern smart enough to slice out the first "johndoe" and "jimjones"? I am using this for IIS rewrite but I think any RegEx should work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
^~/blogs/\w+/(\w+)-(\w+)/(\d{4})/(\d\d)/(\d\d)/([\w-]+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FEymb5b9n7CEb43s)

It just discards the non-dash name. It doesn't know if its equal to the dash name or not. And it also assumes that the date numbers are valid. `9899/45/33` would be matched.

Capture groups:

1. First name
2. Last name
3. Year
4. Month
5. Day
6. Article name

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about IIS rewrites, but this should work:

```
/^~/blogs\/[a-z]+\/ -> ~/blogs/
```

The regular expression will match the start of a string, following by `~/blogs/`, followed by a string of all lowercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use IIS, but this should be at least close.

Pattern:

```
^blogs/\w+/(\w+/)
```

Action

```
blogs/{R:1}
```

[Handy usage doc](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)